# Enable button in activity after the last item clicked

Tags: android, button, click

I am creating an app which has a `button` and a `listview`. My problem is to enable this `button` after all the items in this `listview` has been clicked. Elseway the `button` will be disabled.

How can I checked if all items has been clicked or not?

**here is my adapter** please take a look

```
    public class InstallAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public List<InstallModel> galleryItems;
    ProgressDialog dia;




    public InstallAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<InstallModel> galleryItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.galleryItems = galleryItems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getCount :", galleryItems.size() + "");
        return galleryItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getItem :", galleryItems.get(position) + "");
        return galleryItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("getItemId :", position + "");
        return galleryItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        Button Title;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_result, null);

        Log.e("AgetView", galleryItems.size() + "");

        holder.Title = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInstall1);

        Log.e("gallery postion", galleryItems.get(position) + "");
        holder.Title.setText(galleryItems.get(position).getHeading());

        holder.Title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String url = galleryItems.get(position).getApp_url();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                activity.startActivity(i);


            }
        });

        /*if (position == getCount() - 1) {
            btGoCongrts.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btGoCongrts.setEnabled(true);
        }*/

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to store the positions of all clicked items, and check if all of the required positions are clicked each time user clicks an item in listView. And if all are clicked - enable the button/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way could be adding a list of positions.

You can create an `ArrayList` of `int`. Everytime an user clicks on an `item`, you take this item `position` and you check if the `ArrayList` contains this `index`.

If it doesn't contain it, you add this `int` to the `ArrayList`.

After this you check the count of items in this `ArrayList` and if it's equals to the total count of items in your list, you are done.

Little code:

Add it inside list.[setOnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
ArrayList<int> myIndexes = new ArrayList<>()

//add onitemclick method with this body
if(!myIndexes.contains(position)){
  myIndexes.add(position);
}
if(myIndexes.length == myList.length){
  //enable button
}
```

Obiouvsly you have to replace names and implement methods, but this will work

Comment: thanx this is great but i don't understand where to use this snippet. m a beginner in android

Comment: @anuragshrivastava I suggest you to check some tutorials in android, I always suggest "thenewboston" on yt because it's really full. Btw, you have to add it to the list.onItemClick method, I add it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

For example if you are displaying a list of movies in your list view, then

**Step 1:**  Create a class `Movie` which holds 2 fields named `string movieName` and `boolean flag`

**Step 2:** Set initial `flag` value as `false` for all the movie objects and add in the arraylist. Now use this list to display movie names in your list view.

**Step 3:** Add onclick listener for listview.

**Step 4:** On click of each item in your listview onclick method will be called with `position` as one of the argument. Use this argument to set the corresponding `flag` as `true`. After this line iterate the `movielist` and check whether all the movie objects in the list has flag value as true. In this case enable the `button`.